# Psalm 15:1-5 DSS reference

Tags: exegesis, old-testament

I originally posted this question under the Biblical Hermeneutics Stack Exchange site, but I noticed a number of references to the Dead Sea Scrolls in this community so I thought I'd try my luck here. In reading Robert Alter's book on the Psalms, he mentioned a missing (DSS) verset in Psalm 15  (15:3 — ". . who slanders not with his tongue."). I found a DSS link to these verses in a work by Leon Levy, Dead Sea Scrolls digital library. The specification for these missing words is: Manuscript - 5/6HevPs; Location - 5/6Hev 1b. In trying to find the Plate/Fragment# containing Ps. 15:1-5, I haven't had much success and was hoping someone in this community has traversed this terrain before me and can point me in the right direction. Interestingly, the LXX does have this reference to slandering with the tongue, which introduces a whole other topic/thread regarding the relationship between the Septuagint and the Masoretic text. However, currently that's not my interest as much as the original(?) Hebrew text. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After searching for a site that would provide clues regarding the missing verset in Psalm 15, specifically Ps. 15:3 — “He who slanders not with his tongue,” I found a paper in JSTOR: [Expedition D](https://www.jstor.org/stable/27924841) by Y. Yadin of the Hebrew University, Jerusalem.

Since I still keep up with my Greek and Hebrew from seminary days, I was able to decipher and compare the fragment included in Yadin’s paper with the text of Psalm 15 as found in my Stuttgartensia.

Comment: If you include the specific article you found, quote the relevant text, and perhaps say *how* you found it, this answer could serve as a guide for others with similar problems.

Comment: After searching for a site that would provide clues regarding the missing verset in Psalm 15, specifically Ps. 15:3 — “He who slanders not with his tongue,” I found a link in JSTOR. The title of the paper is, Expedition D, by Y. Yadin of the Hebrew University, Jerusalem. I purchased and downloaded the article. Since I still keep up with my Greek and Hebrew from seminary days, I was able to decipher and compare the fragment included in Yadin’s paper with the text of Psalm 15 as found in my Stuttgartensia.  (https://www.jstor.org/stable/27924841#metadata_info_tab_contents — Yadin's article)

Comment: It's even better if you could edit this info into the body of your answer. +1

Comment: Mike, Do you mean summarizing Yadin's article for the public's consumption instead of merely including the link? I suppose I could do that w/o violating any publishing/copyright stipulations. Let me look into that. Thanks for your time and interest!